# autocomplete="off" on Cakephp helper

Tags: cakephp, autocomplete, cakephp-1.3

I've followed the tutorial from the cakephp book.  I added the autocomplete helper, added the scripts, and it's still not working.  In chrome, if I inspect element and change autocomplete="off" to autocomplete="on", it works but that's only on the live code view.

Controller:

```
function autoComplete() {
    //Partial strings will come from the autocomplete field as
    //$this->data['Post']['subject'] 
    $this->set('items', $this->EstimateDetail->Item->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('Item.description LIKE' => $this->data['Item']['description'].'%'),
                'fields' => array('description')
    )));
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

Autocomplete view:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
 <li><?php echo $item['Item']['description']; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

View File:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('estimate_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('qty');
    echo $ajax->autoComplete('Item.description', '/estimate_details/autoComplete');
    echo $this->Form->input('feet');
    echo $this->Form->input('inches');
    echo $this->Form->input('adjustment');
?>
```

Please help!!

Comment: Can we see some code?  I'm still not up to par with `Psychic v 1.0`

Comment: The autocomplete isn't working.  The html comes out as autocomplete="off".

Comment: The autocomplete html attribute is a different thing. `autocomplete="off"` hints the browser not to save the previously entered field values and suggest them in the future. What you're doing is app-specific autocompletion, so the browser functionality should be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

where did you change that autocomplete option off and on? Can you change that option in the code? At the least, the output from `echo $ajax->autoComplete();` would be nice.

Comment: in firebug or Chrome's Inspect Element.

Comment: can you post the html output of the form?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the controls.js file to my header.  Apparently the Ajax call is in there.